# How to hide a HTTP endpoint in AWS EC2?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, backend

We have a nodeJS server running in AWS EC2 instance, It has many endpoints that should be exposed to the web client on the internet, but we don't want to expose a particular endpoint(e.g: /health status alone) to the public. Any idea how can we do that. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hey there @Srikanth Ganesan,

I am not sure on whether we can hide the endpoints as I am also trying a way where we can hide the endpoints which is a RESTFul client. But instead there are options instead of hiding rather ,

- Introduce authentication using tokens.
- Introduce any encryption algorithm while passing.

Hope this helps in way.

Cheerio

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. But unfortunately, those endpoints cannot be protected using any authentication as those will be used by Monitoring tools like AppDynamics. I couldn't find any better solution so far